# Authservice is not defined here

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Why isn't Authservice being recognized here

```
    void main() => runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
      create: (context) => AuthService(),
      child: MyApp(),
  )
);
```

this is the pubsec file

> ```
> version: 1.0.0+1
>
> environment:
>   sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
>
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>
>   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
>   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
>   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
>   flutter_blue: ^0.6.3+1
>   provider: ^4.0.4
>   firebase_core: ^0.4.4
>   firebase_auth: ^0.15.4
>   cloud_firestore: ^0.13.3
>   auth: ^4.2.0
> ```
>
> this is the build error log Compiler message: lib/main.dart:9:26:
>   Error: 'AuthService' isn't a type.
>   ChangeNotifierProvider(
>                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:10:28: Error: Method not found: 'AuthService'.
>         create: (context) => AuthService(),
>                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:9:3: Error: Type argument 'invalid-type' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier'
>   of the type variable 'T' on 'ChangeNotifierProvider'.
>    - 'ChangeNotifier' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'
>   ('../../Downloads/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart').
>   Try changing type arguments so that they conform to the bounds.
>   ChangeNotifierProvider(   ^
>   ../../Downloads/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-4.0.4/lib/src/change_notifier_provider.dart:98:30:
>   Context: This is the type variable whose bound isn't conformed to.
>   class ChangeNotifierProvider extends
>   ListenableProvider {
>                                ^ lib/main.dart:24:29: Error: 'AuthService' isn't a type.
>           future: Provider.of(context).getUser(),
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/login_page.dart:53:45: Error: 'AuthService' isn't a type.
>                             await Provider.of(context).loginUser(
>                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation:
>   null build failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\Users\sqandil\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle'
>     line: 780
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'C:\Users\sqandil\Downloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''
>   >     finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 14s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you import AuthService?

Comment: That is why I showed my pubspec file

Comment: I mean did you import it into the file that has the ChaneNotifierProvider. You have to import it into the file too

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
import 'auth.dart'; //this should be the package
import 'login_page.dart';

Here is the import statements

Comment: is the auth service from a package or is it something you created

Comment: Also, make sure that AuthService extends ChangeNotifier

Comment: I believe it is auth.dart

Comment: I know but is auth.dart in your `lib` folder or from a third party package

Comment: third party package

Comment: Please check my answer. if it works for you, you can accept it

Comment: If `AuthSercice` class is written by you, would you share the code of that class?

Answer (score 2):

You should be importing it this way `import 'package:auth/auth.dart`

Comment: it didn't fix the issue that I have, but I do thank you for the code

Comment: I guess your issue is because the auth class doesn't extend `ChangeNotifier`.

Comment: So what is funny is that literally yesterday this was not giving me any issues, and now they are giving all of these issues